# Android view with id: '' " is not found! because of lock screen

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I  have two functions which started three android emulators with 10,18,21 sdk versions and than send command to unlock screen.

```
function emulator {
os=$1
density=$2
abi=$3
port=$4

EMULATOR_NAME="hudson_en_US_${density}_${os}_armeabi-v7a"


echo no | /opt/android-sdk/tools/android create avd -f -a -c 100M -n ${EMULATOR_NAME} -t ${os} --abi ${abi}

/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server

/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator -no-boot-anim -ports ${port},$(($port + 1)) -avd ${EMULATOR_NAME}  -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data &

stat=""
while [[ "$stat" -ne "1" ]]
  do
  sleep 20
  #/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-${port}
  stat=$(/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-${port} shell getprop dev.bootcomplete | sed -e "s/\r//")
done

if [ "$?" != '0' ]; then
        echo "Error in run android emulator"
        exit 1;
fi             

/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-${port} logcat > ${EMULATOR_NAME}.log &

/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-${port} shell input keyevent 82
  }

function unlock {

port=$1
/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-${port} shell input keyevent 82

  }

  /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server

  emulator android-21 480 armeabi-v7a 5517
  emulator android-10 160 armeabi 5515
  emulator android-18 320 armeabi-v7a 5569
   sleep 190
   unlock 5517
   unlock 5515
   unlock 5569
```

But my developers told me that their connectedAndroidTests tests failed because of my locked emulators. Piece of fails below:

```
com.tres.one.android.functional.usertype.DifferentAccountDrawerTest >    testEnthusiastShouldSeeSpecificItems[hudson_en_US_160_android-10_armeabi-v7a(AVD) - 2.3.3] [31mFAILED [0m
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: View with id: '2131427462' is not found!
at com.robotium.solo.Solo.getView(Solo.java:2026)
```

Hot to fix this? Because locally everything is ok

Comment: @Sharpedge - No, this has nothing to do with the NDK, so do not tag it as such.  That is a shell script, which runs on the development host.

Comment: yes it was my mistake, sorry i couldn't take that edit back.. as it was waiting for peer review.

Comment: Several existing questions suggest things like `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU` which seems to be working for me right now with an API 21 emulator.  I'm assuming your test emulators do not have pattern locks.